# Loading too much data in cellForRowAtIndexPath causing slow scrolling?

Tags: xml, xcode, parsing, scroll, tableview

I have the following problem: my tableview is scrolling a little bit slower than usual. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    televisionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // creating plist with channel logos
    NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Photos" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"];

    // creating plist with channel names
    NSDictionary *namesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Names" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *namesArray = [namesDictionary objectForKey:@"NamesArray"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"televisionCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in objects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                if (indexPath.row % 2)
                {
                    cell = (televisionCell *)currentObject;
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                    cell.tvLabel.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    cell.backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lightbackgr.png"];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell = (televisionCell *)currentObject;
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                    cell.tvLabel.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    cell.backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-cell.png"];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // getting the channel list array
    BNRAppDelegate *appDelegate = (BNRAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *channelArray = [appDelegate channelsArray];
    NSString *date = [appDelegate str];

    // getting the current time
    NSDateFormatter *hourFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [hourFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH.mm"];
    NSDate *hour = [NSDate date];
    NSString *currHour = [hourFormatter stringFromDate:hour];
    float value = [currHour floatValue];

    // parse different file for every channel
    NSString *dayToString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pik.bg/TV/%@/%@.xml", [channelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], date];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dayToString];
    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // getting every <chas> element from the xml file
    NSString *xPathQueryBegin = @"//elem/chas";
    TFHpple *parserBegin = [TFHpple hppleWithXMLData:webData];
    NSArray *arrayBegin = [parserBegin searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryBegin];
    NSMutableArray *newArrayBegin = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayBegin)
    {
        Listing *begin = [[Listing alloc] init];
        begin.beginHour = [[element firstChild] content];
        if (begin.beginHour != NULL)
        {
            [newArrayBegin addObject:begin.beginHour];
        }
    }

  /*          // converting every object in the array to float number
            NSMutableArray *floatArrayBegin=[NSMutableArray new];
            for(NSString *string in newArrayBegin)
            {
                NSNumber *ourNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: [string floatValue]];
                [floatArrayBegin addObject:ourNumber];
            }
   */

    // getting every <endd> element from the xml file
    NSString *xPathQueryEnd = @"//elem/endd";
    TFHpple *parserEnd = [TFHpple hppleWithXMLData:webData];
    NSArray *arrayEnd = [parserEnd searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryEnd];
    NSMutableArray *newArrayEnd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayEnd)
    {
        Listing *end = [[Listing alloc] init];
        end.endHour = [[element firstChild] content];
        if (end.endHour != NULL)
        {
            [newArrayEnd addObject:end.endHour];
        }
    }

   /*         // converting every object in the array to float number
            NSMutableArray *floatArrayEnd = [NSMutableArray new];
            for(NSString *string in newArrayEnd)
            {
                NSNumber * ourNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: [string floatValue]];
                [floatArrayEnd addObject:ourNumber];
            }
    */

    // gettin every <title> element from the xml file
    NSString *xPathQueryTitle = @"//elem/title";
    TFHpple *parserTitle = [TFHpple hppleWithXMLData:webData];
    NSArray *arrayTitle = [parserTitle searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQueryTitle];
    NSMutableArray *newArrayTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in arrayTitle)
    {
        Listing *title = [[Listing alloc] init];
        title.showTitle = [[element firstChild] content];
        if (title.showTitle != NULL)
        {
            [newArrayTitle addObject:title.showTitle];
        }
    }

    // getting the currently playing show on the channel
    for (int i = 0; i < [newArrayTitle count] - 1; i++)
    {
        if (([[newArrayBegin objectAtIndex:i+1] floatValue] < value) && (value < [[newArrayEnd objectAtIndex:i+2] floatValue]))
        {
            cell.currentlyPlaying.text = [newArrayTitle objectAtIndex:i+1];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

With two words - it is TV Guide app, every cell has channel logo, channel name, and two labels for the currently playing show. I store the images into my project and load them from  plist. The data for the currently playing show is parsed from 11 xml files. I am pretty sure  there is a better way to do this operations, but I am newbie and I don't know what to do to improve my scrolling speed. I guess there are too many operations in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but I don't know other way. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

This is a cell from my app:
[image]

Comment: Why do you parse all the data over and over again? Why not parse it once before the table loads, and then only get the data you need for the specific cell?

Comment: Because I parse different xml files - 11 xml files for each of the channels. For every cell I parse different data if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Then pre-parse the 11 xml files on viewDidLoad/init and then present the relevant data when needed. Do not perform these actions in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Is this possible? Cause I parse them in a for cycle, how to call them every time the loop finishes and starts again with the next value of "i" ?

Comment: With an outer for loop? `for (int i=0; i<namesArray.count; i++)`